# Using jQuery with a WinJS binded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-8, winjs

I am creating some Windows 8 apps and I am using jQuery for alot of my event handling. The problem is that although the jQuery selectors seem to work fine for regular DOM elements, when I try to do a `$('.listItem').click()` event the selector does not actually work.  I think it is because `.listItem` are elements created from the WinJS library at run-time and for some reason the jQuery does not recognize them.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: We need more information. Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List views raise their clicking through the iteminvoked event - click will no be seen for list view items.

If you have other interactive elements that are children on a list view item you can add the class `win-interactive` class to the element you want to see the events from.